Running powershell commands on Active directory joined windows servers
I need to run below winget powershell commands on our domain joined Windows 2019 and 2022 servers. I tried creating Scheduled task via GPO, in that I used System account, but the winget upgrade is not working on  server 2022 with system account, it works fine on 2019 though. I tried using a normal account, but as I understand the GPO doesn't pass the user credentials and hence scheduled task is not created on the systems. I also tried running the commands in startup scripts, but that is also not working.
What are the other ways to run these powershell commands on domain member servers periodically with admin privileges?
winget-install -CheckForUpdate  -force

winget.exe upgrade --all --accept-package-agreements --accept-source-agreements --silent --force


Winget isn't powershell, and winget isn't normally available as the system user since it's an appx.

Please be more specific than "is not working" - what observations did you make to determine it wasn't working, what debugging steps did you go through to obtain more information, and what did you find (error messages, warnings, etc)?

Running winget as the system user from the winget install directory?  https://community.spiceworks.com/t/winget-fails-to-upgrade-apps-when-run-as-system/1058983 Winget doesn't seem ready for prime time.
